# Finding Annihilator of an Ideal in $\mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to construct examples of rings, ideals and annihilators, and have taken the example of $\left( \mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right], +, \cdot \right)$, where $\mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right]$ denote the set of all continuous functions from the interval $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $+$ denotes point - wise addition and $\cdot$ denotes point - wise multiplication.

One can easily show that this forms a commutative ring.

The next thing I tried to obtain is an ideal $I_{x_0} = \left\lbrace f \in \mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right] | f \left( x_0 \right) = 0 \right\rbrace$. Again, it is easy to prove that this is an ideal of $\mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

However, when I tried to find out annihilator of $I_{x_0}$, I got stuck (rather confused). As such, my guess is that the annihilator should be $\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$, where $0: \left[ 0, 1 \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the function $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \left( x \right) = 0$ and is the addtivie identity of the ring $\mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

Although this guess is completely intuitive, I am not able to prove it! I would like help in proving the guess or disproving it!

Comment: Annihilator of what? Any module structure here? Is it the module over itself?

Comment: Annihilator of an ideal will be all those elements of the ring which take all elements of the ideal to the additive identity of the ring. In this case it will be $A \left( I_{x_0} \right) = \left\lbrace h \in \mathscr{C} \left[ 0, 1 \right] | h \cdot f = 0 \right\rbrace$.

Comment: Then your guess could be true. You could prove it by taking specific $f \in I_{x_0}$ to deduce that $h = 0$ at every point except possibly $x_0$, then use the continuity of $h$.

Comment: @xbh The ideal is a module over the ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f \in I_{x_0}$. Especially take
$$
f(x) = |x - x_0|, 
$$
then since $h \cdot f = 0$, $h(x) = 0$ except $x_0$ [since $f(x)\neq 0$ whenever $x \neq x_0$]. Since $h \in \mathcal C[0,1]$, $h(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} h(x) = 0$, so the annihilator is just $ \{0\} $.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = (x-x_0)$ on $[0,1]$. Clearly, $f \in I_{x_0}$. Now consider $h \in Ann(I_{x_0})$. For $x \neq x_0$, $h(x)$ must be $0$ for $h(x)f(x)$ to be $0$.

So $h$ is a continuous functions such that $h(x) = 0$ for any $x \neq x_0$. By the continuity of $h$, we then have $h(x) = 0$ for any $x \in [0,1]$